# Is it possible to restrict the access to assets by business logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, assets

I have created bills, which should be possible to open from admin, but not as a normal user. this bill pdf will be created after certain business process in  app/assets/pdfs.

```
 assets_pdf_url if user_signed_in?
```

Is it possible to restrict specific assets by some rule?

Comment: Are you using apache or IIS ? This can be configured at webserver level

Comment: apache ... but only rails knows the user permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the restricted assets in some folder outside of the public folder, so they cannot be accessed just by visiting a URL, then create an action that uses send_file or send_data. That way you can wrap it up in whatever logic you want.

```
# in controller
def show
  @bill = Bill.find(params[:id])
  if user_signed_in?
    send_file Rails.root.join('bill_pdfs',"#{@bill.id}.pdf")
  else
    redirect_to '/', :error => "Only logged in users may download"
  end
end
```